# How to create an invitation system using Firestore on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have created a list sharing app on android, which uses Firestore DB. It currently has the functionality of creating multiple lists, adding/removing/editing items etc.

Now for the last phase I want to create an invitation system, in which one user invites his friend, and the friend has the ability to accept or decline his invitation.

the current method im working on is creating a temporary "invites" collection , in which the invited user's email will be the document's id, and inside will have a collection of invites: each invite will have id, the id of the desired list , and a status flag (boolean, which indicates if the invite was accpted or not)

what will be the best approach for this matter? I need to keep in mind things like listening for new invitations, handling invitations of non-existing users and more.

hope you can enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know in particular what you are looking for, so I'll write you a possible solution. The method that you are usig will work but the simplest way I can think of for solving this problem would be to create a `map` inside each user document that can contain invites.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users
        |
        --- userEmail
              |
              --- invites
              |     |
              |     --- friendUserEmail: false
              |     |
              |     --- friendUserEmail: false
              |
              --- //Other users details
```

So instead of sharing a list directly, you add the email address of the friend as the key in the map and as the value you can use the boolean false. Now you can use add a `SnapshotListener` on this `invites` location to see if one of its childs has changed the value to true or to see even of there is a new invite. Once the value of a friend is set to true you can basically share that list as explained in this **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)**.

Comment: Hi Tomer! :) Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried this with little enhancements and eventually it worked! In addition I needed to do some tweeks, for example handle the case where the creator of the lists deletes it, and made it deleted for everyone... Im a little worried about securitybut its not an app for production so I give myself a slack. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Yes, so in the "items" collection, under each list I added another collection called "shared by" and added every useremail that accepts an invite. After that, if the creator deletes the list, for every one accepted the invite, I changed a flag to true, and with a listener chacked if this flag has changed. If it changed, delete locally for the user.

Comment: That's nice. Good approach ;)